# Is a Dutch ID card still valid for travel to the UK after Brexit?

Tags: uk, passports, netherlands, brexit, id

Before Brexit, a Dutch ID card was valid to travel to the UK.
Since Brexit, I'm not sure. I hear conflicting information.
Some claim an ID card is still OK, others say a passport is needed.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: A little factsheet here, could be useful for emergency travel: Republic of Ireland is still in the EU (and isn't apparently going anywhere else). It is not a part of Schengen (but it has nothing to do with the right of free movement guaranteed by the EU, therefore you can go there on your ID) in order to be elligible to be a member of a Common Travel Area, together with the UK (and happens to be a member). This could be described in a great simplification as "UK-internal Schengen Zone". Travel from the Rep of Ireland to Northern Ireland (UK) is almost-domestic and island hopping is domestic.

Comment: @MobileDevelopment A source for that is https://www.gov.ie/en/service/e1607-information-for-travel-into-ireland-from-another-eu-country/#

Comment: @MobileDevelopment However, this https://www.gov.uk/guidance/travelling-between-the-uk-and-ireland-isle-of-man-guernsey-or-jersey states the same as in the answer below  And some further context from recent media reports https://www.express.co.uk/news/politics/1661700/albanian-migrants-uk-dublin-airport-route-ireland-soft-border-checks-priti-patel-policy

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A Dutch national *who resides in the UK through the settlement scheme* can continue to use a Dutch national ID card to enter the UK.  There are a few other fairly uncommon circumstances in which a Dutch national ID card may be used.  For everyone else, a passport is necessary.

See https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk:

> You cannot use a national identity card from an EU country, Switzerland, Norway, Iceland or Liechtenstein to enter the UK unless you:
>
> - have settled or pre-settled status under the EU Settlement Scheme, or Jersey, Guernsey or the Isle of Man’s settlement schemes
> - have an EU Settlement Scheme family permit, or the equivalent from Jersey, Guernsey or the Isle of Man
> - have a Frontier Worker permit
> - are an S2 Healthcare Visitor
> - are a Swiss national and have a Service Provider from Switzerland visa

The underlying logic here is that passports are generally required, but use of a national ID card is part of the right of free movement that is preserved after Brexit for certain people who were exercising the right at the time of the UK's withdrawal from the EU.

(The Swiss Service Provider provision will be related to a free movement of services agreement between Switzerland and the EU, or perhaps between Switzerland and the UK, but I do not know the details; I only included it in the quotation for the sake of completeness.)

Comment: That's clear enough. See unless you already live or work in the UK you need a passport.

Comment: @Tonny basically that's it, but even someone who lives in the UK having moved there after Brexit without using the EU settlement scheme (for example, with the same sort of work visa that any non-EU national would need) will need to use a passport.

Comment: Do they stamp the passport?

Comment: @gerrit I think it would depend on whether the traveler uses an APC kiosk, but I have not been to the UK for several years, so I don't know for sure.  From a legal standpoint, a Dutch national visiting the UK as a visa-free visitor is subject to the six-month limit and the prohibition against employment and recourse to public funds.  As I understand it, kiosk users are subject to these restrictions by automatic operation of law whereas others have them stamped into their passports.  But maybe the role of stamps has changed since I last looked into it a few years ago.

Comment: @gerrit I just returned from a holiday visit to the UK last week. No stamp. Not when leaving in Calais (Channel Tunnel) and not at the ferry terminal in Harwich (we returned by ferry to Hoek van Holland). They just glanced briefly at our passports and we were through.

Comment: *is preserved after Brexit for certain people* - not many

Comment: @BernhardDöbler it seems that there are roughly 6 million EUSS applications granted, of whom roughly 1/8 are third-country nationals.  Whether something over 5 million is "not many" is both a matter of opinion and dependent upon context.

Comment: @phoog, with an ID card you needed to see an immigration officer even before Brexit and now even more so, as the automated system does only accept passports. And I also did not get stamps in my passport when I visited the UK last May, train Amsterdam London in, footpassenger on the Harwich Hook ferry back home.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Taking the UK population as approaching 68million, roughly 6million applications is not far off 10% of the entire population. Hard to see how that is *not many*

Comment: @Traveller if you go by the proportion of EU/EEA/CH entries into the UK that are made under the EUSS (and other exceptions) it could be fairly small.

Comment: You may consider me skeptical that somebody could use a Dutch ID to demonstrate that they were a Swiss national.

Comment: @AndrewRay of course.  As I said, I included that for the sake of completeness, since the material I was quoting applies to more countries than just the Netherlands, but I figured it would be easier for readers to discount the irrelevant bullet point on their own than to wonder what had been removed and replaced by "..." or whatever else.  And I didn't want to omit it silently because it would be inaccurate to quote something that seemed to enumerate all the applicable exceptions for EU/EEA/CH nationals but didn't in fact include them all.

Comment: *"A Dutch national who resides in the UK through the settlement scheme can continue to use a Dutch national ID card to enter the UK."* This sentence sounds a bit self-contradicting. Presumably the ID card is not sufficient in this case; at the very least, it should be accompanied by a second document attesting that the Dutch national does indeed reside in the UK through the settlement scheme.

Comment: @Stef I don't know how an immigration officer determines whether someone presenting a national ID card is eligible to use it instead of a passport, but it's possible that there are ways to do so without requiring the presentation of an additional document, for example by querying a database of settlement scheme participants.