# Permanent resident re-entering UK on different passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, uk-residents, italian-citizens, new-zealand-citizens

I have dual New Zealand and Italian citizenship, currently living in the UK.

I have settled status in the UK under my Italian passport, which is currently expired.

I have an appointment to renew it, but I'd like to go to Europe for a specific event before it can be renewed (2 day event).

If I exit and re-enter the UK on my New Zealand passport will that cause issues for my settled status? Or any other problems at the border? Should I even attempt it?

Comment: Apparently it should be possible since once you have settled status you are allowed to spend time outside the UK (up to 5 years) without jeopardizing your settled status. However, if you ever consider asking for uk citizenship in the future I would be very careful as the time you spend in the UK after you return under a NZ passport might not necessarily count as time spent in the UK under your settled status.

Comment: Can you use your Italian ID card, given that you have settled status https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175972/is-a-dutch-id-card-still-valid-for-travel-to-the-uk-after-brexit?

Comment: About naturalisation's concerns raised by Hoki:  it's a good idea to make a Subject Access Request to confirm that the UK has a coherent view of your travel in/out, before filing your naturalisation papers.

Answer (score 2):

To re-enter Britain you need two things.

1. A valid travel document (passport)
2. Proof of your resident status in Britain.

As I understand it your proof of residence is associated with your Italian passport which is expired.

The obvious and foolproof approach is to carry both your passports with you. Use the unexpired NZ one where it works. When you return to the UK present both. Based on your Italian passport Immigration can determine your residency from your Italian passport whether it is expired or not.

If the UK knows about your NZ passport it's likely they can check your residency status based on it. But for the tiny extra effort of carrying a second passport versus the possible complications if they can't, I would carry both.

It may be wise to renew your Italian passport.

Comment: UK doesn't provide physical proof of settled status for EU citizens, so there's nothing stamped in his Italian passport (that's not what he meant with "I have settled status in the UK under my Italian passport")

Comment: Good point, but I don't think it fundamentally changes the answer.